# Block stored as instance variable becomes nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I'm trying to store a block in an instance variable in my project.  Here's where I declare the instance variable:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)void (^loginCompletedTask)();
```

I'm assigning the variable by calling this method:

```
- (void)requireLoggedInForBlock:(void (^)())completion {
    self.loginCompletedTask = completion;

    // Display an alert view that requires username and password input
}
```

After the first line of this method, `self.loginCompletedTask` is non-nil and logs in the debugger with type `NSMallocBlock`.  However, when I actually need to run the block after the login alert view is returned, it has become nil.

I've tried:

- Declaring with `strong` instead of `copy`,
- Setting as `self.loginCompletedTask = ^{completion();};`,
- Setting the variable directly, instead of using a property (`_loginCompletedTask = ...`).

What am I missing?

Comment: And you are pretty sure that the object of the  in which you requireLoggedInForBlock: was not de-alloc()ed by that time (just put a NSLog in its dealloc() to check).

Comment: Yes, because I'm logging the value of my block within that object.  If it was nil, none of that code would run.  Thanks for your quick reply btw.

Comment: And you didn't allocate a NEW copy of your object?

Comment: Hmm, my guess is that you are doing something to it somewhere else, because I have the exact same thing except that mine is `strong` instead of `copy` and takes a parameter, and it is working just fine. My guess is that the object that is completing the task might for some reason be a different one than the one you set this variable in or that you are releasing it somewhere else.

Comment: @HotLicks no, when I log it it's nil, not an empty block.

Comment: @Jsdodgers maybe that's happening, but I'm not doing that directly--I've checked every use of the variable.

Comment: @aopsfan: You could try to set a watchpoint on `self->_ loginCompletedTask` in the debugger to see where it is nilled.

Comment: @Jsdodgers upon further inspection, it was a different object, no idea how I missed that.  Thanks for thinking of that, you probably saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: So you DID allocate a new copy of your object.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  a problem unrelated to the question.

Comment: How exactly can a question be about something it's not related to?

Comment: @aopsfan - It isn't -- that's the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it had nothing to do with storing the block incorrectly.  I was actually creating a new object of the same class as the one that stored the block but forgot to copy over the actual block.  Thus, the methods that were being hit that logged out the value of `self.loginCompletedBlock` were being received by the other object rather than the one that assigned the variable to begin with.

Thanks all for your help, it always amazes me how SO users are so willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are the only objects (to date) created on the stack rather than the heap. If you want to keep a block around longer than the life of the stack frame in which it was created, you must `copy` the block (the copy is heap based). Even using a strong pointer will not stop the block from going away when the stack frame is popped.

ADDED: the comments are correct, having a copy property is sufficient. My bad, I forgot the copy attribute was there.

Comment: My property is declared as (nonatomic, copy)--is that enough to ensure copying happens?

Comment: But that is exactly what `@property (..., copy)` already does.